# Symfony2 login issue using dynamic login url

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have dynamic url for login using FosUserBundle.

**Firstly, i logged in to my site using a url "12.112.222:8080/club111/backend/signin"  and logged out using the url "12.112.222:8080/club111/backend/signout".**

**After that i just changed the login url identifier to "12.112.222:8080/twilight/backend/signin" where club111 and twilight are dynamic values.**

**When login the second time, server returns the error "You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration."**

First time it works well...But the second time(when changing the argument), it doesn't.

**But when clearing the cache after first time, it works fine...
Is there any way to reset the login_path in security.yml or in cache...?**

Below given my full security.yml configuration

```
      security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USERS
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USERS, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    frontend:
      pattern:    /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/.*
      provider:   fos_userbundle
      anonymous: ~          
      form_login:
          check_path: fairgate_user_security_check
          login_path: fos_user_security_login
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
          csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
          intention: authenticate               
          post_only: true
          remember_me: true
          #use_referer: true
          #always_use_default_target_path: true
          default_target_path: contact_index
          use_referer:                    false
          require_previous_session: false
      logout:
          path:   fairgate_user_security_logout
          target: fos_user_security_login
          invalidate_session: true
          delete_cookies:
              a: { path: null, domain: null }
              b: { path: null, domain: null }
      remember_me:
          key:      "123456"
          lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
          path:     fos_user_security_login
          domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
          always_remember_me: true

access_control:
    fos_user_security_login:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/signin
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_resetting:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/request
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_security_check:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/login_check
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_resetting_send_email:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/send-email
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_resetting_check_email:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/check-email
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_resetting_reset:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/reset/.*
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    fos_user_resetting:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/request
        roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]

    admin_users:
        path: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/.*
        roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED]


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USERS
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_denied_url: /%cluburlidentifier%/backend/unauthorized
```

Main routing.yml under config folder is looks like ...

```
common_utility:
   resource: "@CommonUtilityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
   prefix:   /{url_identifier}/backend/
```

And the routing.yml under the CommonUtilityBundle is like...

```
fos_user_security_login:
   pattern:  /signin
   defaults: { _controller: CommonUtilityBundle:Security:login }

fairgate_user_security_check:
   pattern:  /login_check
   defaults: { _controller: CommonUtilityBundle:Security:check }

fairgate_user_security_logout:
   pattern:  /signout
   defaults: { _controller: CommonUtilityBundle:Security:logout }
```

Someone please help me....

Comment: I don't understand *club111 and twilight are dynamic values*. Dynamic  how? Can you also extend your `security.yml` paste so we can see the `firewalls` and `access_control` parts as well? Better - the whole `security.yml`

Comment: What is the url for the firewall, please post the full firewall section from your security.yml. Although it looks to me, that the your  check path is not under the firewall